# Accessing gitlab postgres omnibus database

Tags: postgresql, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to access my gitlab omnibus's postgres installation from other apps so that I can share data within. How do I find the login information, eg user/pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There should be no password.**

If you have `sudo` access on the machine where you installed GitLab Omnibus, then you can confirm this with:

```
sudo grep gitlab-psql /etc/shadow
```

and it should show '`!`' in the password field, something like:

```
gitlab-psql:!!:16960::::::
```

Faced with a similar goal (accessing GitLab's DB in order to derive some usage plots, counts of issues opened/closed over time, etc.), here is what I did (assuming `sudo` ability):

```
sudo su -l gitlab-psql
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys << "EOF"
<your ssh public key here>
EOF

chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Once this is done, first check that you can `ssh` to that host as `gitlab-psql`, using the proper key, of course, either from a remote host: `ssh gitlab-psql@my-gitlab-host`, or locally: `ssh gitlab-psql@localhost`.

After that, you should be able to access the DB from other apps via `ssh`. For example, here is a way to query the DB directly from a Python notebook (running on another host somewhere in EC2), and using Pandas:

```
def gitlab_query(query):
    cmdargs = [
        'ssh', 'gitlab-psql@my-gitlab-host',
        f"""/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -h /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/ gitlabhq_production -A -F $'\t' -c "{query}" """,
    ]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdargs, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    try:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout=15)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        proc.kill()
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
    errors = errs.decode('utf-8')
    if errors:
        raise ValueError(errors)
    result = outs.decode('utf-8')
    result = result[:result.rfind('\n', 0, -1)]
    return result


# simple example
# NOTE: as is, this is incomplete, because many issues are closed by other
# actions (e.g. commits or merges) and in those cases, there is no
# closed_at date. See further below for better queries. (not included in
# this SO answer as this is getting beyond the scope of the question).

q = """
select
  b.name, a.title, a.created_at, a.closed_at
from issues a inner join projects b on (a.project_id = b.id)
where closed_at > '2018-01-09' and b.name='myproject'
order by 1,4 limit 10
"""

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(gitlab_query(q)), sep='\t', parse_dates=['created_at', 'closed_at'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a gitlab-praefect node as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/gitaly/praefect.html#praefect) and you are using AWS EC2 and a AWS postgres and want to check if those two can communicate.

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/psql -U YourExistingUsername -d template1 -h RDS-POSTGRES-ENDPOINT
```